# Show four equal integrals$\int_0^1e^{4/\ln x}dx=\int_0^12xe^{2/\ln x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{2x}{\ln^2x}e^{2/\ln x}dx=\int_0^1\frac4{\ln^2x}e^{4/\ln x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

While investigating Mellin transforms I noticed that the following four integrals are all equal.

> How do you show that these four integrals are equal?$$ \int_0^1 e^{\frac{4}{\log(x)}}~dx =\int_0^1 2xe^{\frac{2}{\log(x)}}~dx=\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{\log^2(x)}e^{\frac{2}{\log(x)}}~dx= \int_0^1 \frac{4}{\log^2(x)}e^{\frac{4}{\log(x)}}~dx $$

Now I want to be able to prove that they are all equal. My attempt was to show that the difference between each pair of them is zero.

$$ \int_0^1 e^{\frac{4}{\log(x)}}-2xe^{\frac{2}{\log(x)}}~dx= \int_0^1 e^{\frac{2}{\log(x)}}\bigg(e^{\frac{2}{\log(x)}}-2x\bigg)~dx \overset{\log( x) \to x}= \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{\frac{2}{x}+2x}\bigg(e^{\frac{2}{x}+2x}-e^{2x} \bigg)~dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{\frac{2}{x}+2x}\bigg( e^{2x}\bigg(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1 \bigg)\bigg(e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1\bigg)\bigg)~dx $$

However I got stuck here.

Comment: The first inequality is merely the transformation $x\to x^2$ and the last the inverse $x\to\sqrt{x}$ so you only need to show the middle equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{4}{\ln^2 x}e^{\frac{4}{\ln x}}~dx
= -\int_0^1 x \> d\left( e^{\frac{4}{\ln x}}\right) 
\overset{IBP} =\int_0^1 e^{\frac{4}{\ln x}}~dx\\
&\int_0^1 \frac{4}{\ln^2x}e^{\frac{4}{\ln x}}~dx
\overset{x\to x^2 }= \int_0^1 \frac{2x}{\ln^2 x}e^{\frac{2}{\ln x}}~dx\\
&\int_0^1 e^{\frac{4}{\ln x}}~dx \overset{x\to x^2} =\int_0^1 2xe^{\frac{2}{\ln x}}~dx
\end{align}